# Azure A Records gives 404

Tags: azure, dns, web, ip

I have a website hosted at Azure, registered {0}.com and www.{0}.com as custom domain, both are working fine!

But if I use the plain IP which I put into the A record, it gives me an 404.

My understanding is that the plain IP address should also return the website, am I wrong? If it should do so, whats my mistake?

Comment: You're seeing the side affect of multi-site hosting on a web server utilising HTTP host headers.  The default site on the web server hosting your site has a missing default page which is why you get a 404 not found.  This isn't really an Azure-only issue - any large scale hosting will have this sort of thing.

Comment: okay, so this is no failure, but an expected behavoir and an A record actually doesnt make sense in this scenario

Answer (score -1):

Did you create an “awverify” record in your domain register? You need to create a special CNAME record that is used to verify you own your domain. This is required if you are going to use A record, and is not necessary for CNAME. You can check http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/.

Comment: Actually, awverify records are also necessary for CNAME records, and are correctly set as the domains {0}.com and www.{0}.com are working!

Comment: I don't think so. Actually I had some CNAME records for my Azure Websites without awverify.

Comment: Well the the Azure ocumentation says: "Microsoft Azure must verify that you are authorized to configure the custom domain name to point to your Microsoft Azure website. To verify authorization, create a CNAME resource record with your DNS provider that points from either www.yourdomain.com to {0}.azurewebsites.net, or from awverify.www.yourdomain.com to awverify.{0}.azurewebsites.net" But however, thats not the point of my question ;)